# Issue with react-addon-test-utils createElement

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, jsdom

I am updating my code from the now deprecated react/addons package to the react-addon-test-utils package. I use jsdom and inject a document and window element, as shown below.

```
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import chai from 'chai';
import chaiImmutable from 'chai-immutable';

const doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
const win = doc.defaultView;

global.document = doc;
global.window = win;

Object.keys(window).forEach((key) => {
  if (!(key in global)) {
    global[key] = window[key];
  }
});

chai.use(chaiImmutable);
```

#### And here is my unit test.

```
import {expect} from 'chai';
import ErrorBlock from '../src/Controls/ErrorBlock';
import React from 'react-addons-test-utils';

const {renderIntoDocument, scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass, Simulate}
  = React;

describe('ErrorBlock', () => {

  it('renders properly', () => {
    const id = 'test';
    const message = 'my message';
    const alertStyle = "alert-danger";
    const component = renderIntoDocument(
      <ErrorBlock id={id} message={message} alertStyle={alertStyle} />
    );
    const spanEntry = scryRenderedDOMComponentsWithClass(component, id + 'AlertMessage');
    expect (spanEntry.length).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

I am in the process of getting unit testing setup for a React UI module for use on some projects. However, when I switch over to the new react-addons-test-utils package, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: _reactAddonsTestUtils2.default.createElement is not a function
```

This error occurs on the line where I define my component.

Why am I getting this error ONLY when using the new package?

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/test-utils.html#renderintodocument You will need to have window, window.document and __window.document.createElement__ globally available before you import React.

Comment: This is why I included the first block of code. They already are.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I see `window.document.createElement` globally available and only see these `global.document = doc;
global.window = win;`.

Comment: That's what the .forEach is doing. I can also show you output from console.log(document.window.createElement). Trust me, it's there.

Comment: @Sinistralis Did you figure out the issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: No I did not, I've been using the deprecated version until I find an answer.

Comment: Just following up on this, I have since moved to Teaspoon for testing, and possibly making the jump to Enzyme. The tools in these libraries are pretty nice, so for anyone else having this issue I recommend looking into them.

Answer (score 3):

It may be late, but i think this is our solution . Let change from :

```
const doc = jsdom.jsdom('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
const win = doc.defaultView;

global.document = doc;
global.window = win;
```

to :

```
const doc = new jsdom.JSDOM('<!doctype html><html><body></body></html>');
const win = doc.window;

global.document = win.document;
global.window = win;
```

It will fix all of our issues